# Background Transparency Error in a PHP Page Inside Iframe

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Well that's even kinda surprising to ask but I do have this problem.

And I guess it's only for the lovely explorer: IE.

Firefox, Chrome etc have no problems. But when you open with IE... Well, we all know how talented it is to ruin things down.

Here is the structure of the page:

```
#main div
-#content div
--iframe
---form.php
```

I add in to this part of code to any element I found: `style="background-color:transparent;"`

But it keeps viewing the background color white. When I change the css file declared in form.php, `body { bg:transparent }` to `bg:#ccc;` or to any color, it works and shows the color. But when I remove all the colors, it's white. Also when I add transparent color, it's same.

I have an idea actually, but just wanna make sure if that's why. In my form, the html elements are written with php echo function, too. For example: `echo '<tr>Your Name:</tr>'`
Because there are some variables declared. If this is why, then I have to rebuild the form. But if you have any other opinion, please, lighten me up.

Comment: I think IE has a proprietary attribute `allowtransparency`, have you tried it?

Comment: What @znarkus says - that's probably the answer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh no, shame on me. Works like a charm. Thank you so much :)

Comment: If your question has been solved, please do not edit the title, but provide the answer in the answer section and accept it. This will improve the structure of the site and will help others to find the actual answer.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer :P

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel,
Had to do that way because @Znarkus didn't reply but wrote a comment. But I guess we solved the problem. Won't happen again.

Comment: @Confeng don't worry about it :) You can still post the answer yourself though and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IE has a proprietary attribute `allowtransparency`.

:-)

But that will upset the HTML validators.